# Using a brand name in a product which I will sell

Tags: law, selling

I own a company where we manufacture vinyl stickers which wrap up devices, varying from phones to game consoles. We had plans to create a design for Game of Thrones, but we are unsure how this bit of copyright works.

Do we need to obtain any license or such to be able to use the 'Game of Thrones' name in our product name? If so, what is the general way to acquire such a license?

Pardon me if this question does not suit the site. I tried to find a subsite where this fits the best. Please migrate it (or suggest me) if I failed to get things right.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not about personal finance.

Comment: @ChrisW.Rea I have no idea where else I could ask this. There was an Area51 suggestion going about law which used this question as example but as that's in Area51 I thought this would perhaps work..

Comment: The better place might be the startups discussion. Or might not; they might tell you to seek legal advice too.

Comment: http://startups.stackexchange.com/ is probably where to ask

Answer (score 1):

You ***CAN NOT*** safely use someone else's trademark in conjunction with your product without permission, except when saying you're not the same thing (Better than/as good as/compare with has been ruled ok in the US; it may not be elsewhere.)

Your best bet is something that has the same general style and *suggests* GOT or the books it's based on, but even there you need to be careful; visuals can also be trademarked, and there's the concept of "derivitive work".

In the US there are also exceptions for a very specific definition of  "parody". Standard example: without permission, it is legally safer to show Mickey Mouse as a drug-addicted pedophile -- implicitly commenting on his normal "squeeky clean" (sorry) reputation -- than to use a respectful rendering of him. That's one of the things Mad Magazine has relied upon. Your project would definitely not qualify for this exception as you've described it.

How much do you think you're likely to be sued for, and how willing are you to take that risk?

Note that not making money doesn't mean you aren't infringing, but it does mean they're less likely to sue your pants off and more likely to just hit you with a cease-and-desist order.

(I sometimes write parodies; I've had reason to learn the basics... but ***i am not a lawyer*** and legal advice is out of bounds anyway. Find your own expert.)